# Unable to get the next question after the record is deleted in PHP quiz

Tags: php

Hi i am developing a online quiz based application but facing a problem in this while taking the test.I am inserting questions and multiple choices in different tables it is working fine.For deleting and Deleting as well its working fine.But facing the problem while taking exam.

For Example if i have added questions and deleted one question from the middle of this then while taking the exam we are not getting the next question.Here are my tables.

```
Questions Database Table:

question_number  question_no  text  status
1                 1           html    1
2                 2           php     1
3                 2           html    0
4                 3           html    1
```

Choices Database Table:

```
id   question_number   is_correct  text   status
1       1                1        abc       1
2       1                0        abc       1
3       1                0        abc       1
4       1                0        abc       1 
5       2                0        abcdfd    1
6       2                1        abcdsf    1
7       2                0        abcdsf    1
8       2                0        abcsdfg   1
9       3                1        abchdfgh  0
10      3                0        abfdhdfc  0
11      3                0        afdhgbc   0
12      3                0        adfhbc    0 
13      4                1        abchdfgh  1
14      4                0        abfdhdfc  1
15      4                0        afdhgbc   1
16      4                0        adfhbc    1
```

Here their are 4 question in total in that 3 are in active state and one is inactive so i need to show these active questions. but for me is displaying only two questyions for third question it is displaying like below image attahced.

[image]

Here is the code for this:

```
<?php 
$query ="SELECT * FROM questions where status='1'";
//Get results
 $results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
 $total = $results->num_rows;
 ?>
 <a href="question.php?n=1" class="start">Start Quiz</a>
```

Question.php File:

```
<?php
$number = (int) $_GET['n']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE status='1'";
//Get result
$results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$total = $results->num_rows;        

$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions`
            WHERE question_number = $number AND status='1'";
//Get result

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$question = $result->fetch_assoc();

$query = "SELECT * FROM `choices`
            WHERE question_number = $number AND status='1'";
//Get results
$choices = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
 ?> 
        <div class="current">Question <?php echo $question['question_number']; ?> of <?php echo $total; ?></div>
        <p class="question">
            <?php echo $question['text']; ?>
        </p>
        <form method="post" action="process.php">
            <ul class="choices">
                <?php while($row = $choices->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                    <li><input name="choice" type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /><?php echo $row['text']; ?></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
        </form>
```

If i give the url as like this then it is displaying question

```
http://www.example.com/admin/question.php?n=4
```

Then it is displaying the 4th question if in the url n=3 then it is not displaying the question.

Comment: Don’t go by record IDs, go by their order. Select the records that have a question number higher than your current one, ORDER them by number in ascending order - and then LIMIT the result of that to only one record.

Comment: @04FS not getting what you are saying

Comment: @B001ᛦ that  what is their any other solutions]

Comment: Not getting what you are not getting. Which part do you have trouble with? Selecting by an incremented ID makes little sense, if records can get removed and then leave “holes”. So instead select the _next_ record from the set of records that are “larger” than this record, by whatever the chosen sorting criterion is. WHERE clause for the “larger” part, ORDER BY to get _those_ records in order from “smallest” to “largest”, and LIMIT 1 to only get the first of those.